# What are the options for a prepaid SIM card in Germany?

Tags: germany, cellphones

I'll be staying in Berlin for one month and I have an unlocked iPhone (GSM) that I'd like to use while I'm here. What are my choices for SIM cards and packages that include data?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This wiki is a very good source of info: http://www.prepaid-wiki.de/

Many companies offer prepaid SIM cards.  [blau.de](http://www.blau.de/) is a good option.  I use a [NettoKom](http://www.nettokom.de/) SIM card, which is a re-branded blau card that is sold for 5€ in Netto grocery stores; other discount grocery stores (Lidl, ALDI, etc) have their own offerings.   A one-month data plan will cost 10-15€.

I just saw an ad for what appears to be an amazing deal from Telekom (the largest operator) that seems to include unlimited use of the Telekom network for only 10€ per month: [Xtra pre-paid card](http://www.t-mobile.de/tarifuebersicht-prepaid-tarife/0,21864,25245-_,00.html#grp=0&dev=0)

Comment: The Xtra pre-paid card is too good to be true. I read the details of the offer and your connection is throttled to 64kbps after 300MB usage.

Comment: 64kbps is very good indeed, more than by old-style modem connection. In Poland t-mobile trims transfer to 10kbps after 100MB usage :(

Comment: I was surprised by blau.de's lack of coverage. I was just in Berlin and couldn't get access in the apartment I was renting, and often couldn't in many outdoor places. I don't know if the other carriers are any better.

Comment: blau.de uses Eplus mobile network. You won't get any better with any other of the many Eplus resellers. You could try Congstar (T-Mobile/D1 network) or BILDmobil (Vodafone/D2 network), the "D network" carriers are said to have a better network than the "E network" carriers.

Answer (score 6):

[The answer from @nibot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/8144/2560) is very good, i just want to add something: You said that you have iPhone, so you need micro-sim and not every operator sells prepaid-micro-sim-cards. So i find that page: 
http://www.der-prepaid-vergleich.de/Micro-sim/micro-sim-prepaid-tarife.html

Answer (score 5):

I've had a good experience with [Fonic](http://www.fonic.de).

As of the time I'm writing this, they offer a 500MB data plan for 10 euro a month.
They also have a very convenient website (though it is in German, it's usable through Google translate), which allows you to perform almost all the actions you might need.
Also, they have a customer service number which (usually after only a short wait) gets you straight to an English-speaking human. This is a big plus for non-German speakers who can't get through the automated voice menu in German.

Fonic don't have their own stores, but you can get their SIM cards in partner stores that you can find [here](http://www.fonic.de/filialfinder).

Answer (score 1):

The best network in Germany is the one from T-Mobile. For tourists it is best to use an call-abroad-oriented service like Lebara that uses the T-Mobile network. They have great bundles, e.g. 3 GB data for one month, or 1 GB and 1000 free minutes to cell phones and fixed lines in 39 countries. Another good option for mobile data would be the 3GB card from Beachsim.

One can either buy such German pay-as-you-go SIM card in a kiosk, gas / petrol station, or buy it online prior to you stay in Germany. That is what I did and it worked great for me. You can buy for instance [the 3 GB German data SIM card from Beachsim here](http://www.beachsim.com/product/germany-3-gb-1-eur-credit/?lang=en).

Hope this helps for your Berlin trip. Enjoy!

Comment: You're talking about Lebara, but posting a link to beachsim !? Are you employee of this company?

Comment: No. For an international traveller it helps to receive his local payg sim card beforehand. That is what I was sharing. Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Check out [My German Phone](http://www.mygermanphone.de/), they explain how to get all kinds of German SIM cards.

You can even request free SIM cards from some of the major German service providers: http://www.mygermanphone.de/free-sim-cards/